# Can't see Delete/Setting buttons for Branch in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, branch

Since last couple of weeks, I assume after some GUI modifications of Azure DevOps, I am unable to scroll horizontally to reach up to the Delete/Settings/Security buttons/menu on Branches view of my Azure DevOps.

[image]

How come no one else is facing this issue?
I am not able to delete old branches, neither update security settings, because I just can't scroll any further to the right!!!

I tried with Chrome as well as Safari, but issue is common across browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have enabled `New Repos landing pages` preview feature.

[image]

In the new page, the menu sits in the end of the branch, check the screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: I am aware of the Menu position, just unable to reach there :) Not sure why there is no horizontal scroll enabled.. Anyway, I could access the Menu after Zooming out in my browser!!